# Trying to format text field for date entry automatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am trying to add automatic date formatting to a text field in my app, however I have been having issues.

Basically, I would like the text field to format numbers that the users enter as they type in this format - xx-xx-xxxx. The actual formatting seems to work, however the problem:

1) The text field adds a '0' once the user begins typing.
2) The text field does not update the formatting until the delete button is tapped.

Here is my code:

```
    func textFieldChanged(textField: UITextField!, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: NSString!) -> Bool {
    var formatter = NSNumberFormatter()

    var lengthString: String = string
    let newLength = countElements(transactionDateInput.text!) + countElements(lengthString) - range.length

    if string.length == 0 {
        formatter.groupingSeparator = "/"
        formatter.groupingSize = 4
        formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
        formatter.secondaryGroupingSize = 2

        var num: NSString = transactionDateInput.text
        num = num.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("-", withString: "")
        var str: NSString = formatter.stringFromNumber(NSNumber.numberWithDouble(num.doubleValue))
        transactionDateInput.text = str
        return true && newLength <= 10
    } else {
        formatter.groupingSeparator = "/"
        formatter.groupingSize = 2
        formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
        formatter.secondaryGroupingSize = 2

        var num: NSString = transactionDateInput.text
        if num.isEqualToString("") {
            num = num.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("-", withString: "")
            var str: NSString = formatter.stringFromNumber(NSNumber.numberWithDouble(num.doubleValue))
            transactionDateInput.text = str
        }
        return true && newLength <= 10
    }
}
```

How can I solve these issues?

Comment: From a usability standpoint, I find it far easier to use a date picker as long as there's an easy way to navigate to distant dates.  (My birth date is a *long* time ago.)  It is also unsettling when things format themselves while I'm typing.

Comment: I had considered using a date picker, however it would have required a large redesign. Also, although I somewhat agree with you in regards to formatting sometimes being unsettling, it is consistent with other elements of my app.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about an invisible text field?  Then you can capture text as typed and output formatted text in a visible text field.  This way you control everything.